# kafkaproducer is all right but kafkaconsumer failed when using kafka connector

Tags: python, apache-flink, pyflink

I'm using pyflink-1.17.0, java11, flink1.17.0 on linux.
I run a local cluster and try to run the example code below.

```py
import logging
import sys

from pyflink.common import Types
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.datastream.connectors.kafka import FlinkKafkaProducer, FlinkKafkaConsumer
from pyflink.datastream.formats.json import JsonRowSerializationSchema, JsonRowDeserializationSchema


# Make sure that the Kafka cluster is started and the topic 'test_json_topic' is
# created before executing this job.
def write_to_kafka(env):
    type_info = Types.ROW([Types.INT(), Types.STRING()])
    ds = env.from_collection(
        [(1, 'hi'), (2, 'hello'), (3, 'hi'), (4, 'hello'), (5, 'hi'), (6, 'hello'), (6, 'hello')],
        type_info=type_info)

    serialization_schema = JsonRowSerializationSchema.Builder() \
        .with_type_info(type_info) \
        .build()
    kafka_producer = FlinkKafkaProducer(
        topic='test_json_topic',
        serialization_schema=serialization_schema,
        producer_config={'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092', 'group.id': 'test_group'}
    )

    # note that the output type of ds must be RowTypeInfo
    ds.add_sink(kafka_producer)
    env.execute()


def read_from_kafka(env):
    deserialization_schema = JsonRowDeserializationSchema.Builder() \
        .type_info(Types.ROW([Types.INT(), Types.STRING()])) \
        .build()
    kafka_consumer = FlinkKafkaConsumer(
        topics='test_json_topic',
        deserialization_schema=deserialization_schema,
        properties={'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092', 'group.id': 'test_group_1'}
    )
    kafka_consumer.set_start_from_earliest()

    env.add_source(kafka_consumer).print()
    env.execute()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO, format="%(message)s")

    env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
    env.add_jars("file:///path/to/flink-sql-connector-kafka-1.17.0.jar")

    print("start writing data to kafka")
    write_to_kafka(env)

    print("start reading data from kafka")
    read_from_kafka(env)
```

which writes data to kafka and then reads from it.
I'm running the code with `python3 kafka_json_format.py` instead of submitting it to the cluster.

The data write succeeded with data on the kafka, but data read failed with `No module named pyflink`.

Details are below:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to execute the command: python -c import pyflink;import os;print(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(pyflink.__file__)), 'bin'))
output: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pyflink

    at org.apache.flink.python.util.PythonEnvironmentManagerUtils.execute(PythonEnvironmentManagerUtils.java:220)
    at org.apache.flink.python.util.PythonEnvironmentManagerUtils.getPythonUdfRunnerScript(PythonEnvironmentManagerUtils.java:157)
    at org.apache.flink.python.env.process.ProcessPythonEnvironmentManager.createEnvironment(ProcessPythonEnvironmentManager.java:59)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.createPythonExecutionEnvironment(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:434)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.lambda$open$0(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:262)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.memory.MemoryManager.lambda$getSharedMemoryResourceForManagedMemory$5(MemoryManager.java:539)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.memory.SharedResources.createResource(SharedResources.java:126)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.memory.SharedResources.getOrAllocateSharedResource(SharedResources.java:72)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.memory.MemoryManager.getSharedMemoryResourceForManagedMemory(MemoryManager.java:555)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.open(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:265)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.process.AbstractExternalPythonFunctionOperator.open(AbstractExternalPythonFunctionOperator.java:57)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.process.AbstractExternalDataStreamPythonFunctionOperator.open(AbstractExternalDataStreamPythonFunctionOperator.java:85)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.process.AbstractExternalOneInputPythonFunctionOperator.open(AbstractExternalOneInputPythonFunctionOperator.java:117)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.process.ExternalPythonProcessOperator.open(ExternalPythonProcessOperator.java:64)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.RegularOperatorChain.initializeStateAndOpenOperators(RegularOperatorChain.java:107)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreGates(StreamTask.java:734)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$SynchronizedStreamTaskActionExecutor.call(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:100)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreInternal(StreamTask.java:709)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restore(StreamTask.java:675)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:952)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:921)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:745)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:562)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

I have corrected the version of pyflink and java to current state but still the same result. Interesting thing is in this code, write kafka succeeded but read failed with no pyflink. How could I solve this?

Comment: flink-sql-connector-kafka-1.15.0.jar is incompatible with Flink 1.17.0.

Comment: sorry, I edited some place on the example code, connector I'm using is flink-sql-connector-kafka-1.17.0.jar @DavidAnderson

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using a virtualenv , this maybe caused by pythonpath

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).